# How to execute code on every page load, but only after route controller executed?

Tags: laravel

I'm working on a Laravel based project and I need to execute some "basic" php code on every page load. Until now, I placed my code in boot() from AppServiceProvider. It works well, but I need to execute my "basic" code only after the code from route's controller has been already executed.

I've already searched in laravel's official docs, but I still did not figured out how to do it.

This is how my route looks:

```php
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/profile/email/{profile_id?}', 'profileController@profileHandleEmail')->name('profile/email');
```

The result I want to achive is to execute the code from profileController@profileHandleEmail before the "basic" code from AppServiceProvider.

Which would be the best way to do this? I guess it can't be achived using AppServiceProvider.

Comment: You can run your php code in layout.blade.php file

Comment: Take a look at middlewares. You can create a global after middleware
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware#global-middleware

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The suggested way to achieve what you want is to use middleware:

Run `php artisan make:middleware PostProcess`

It should generate the a middleware class under `App\Http\Middleware`

```
class PostProcess {

      public function handle($request, $next) {
          $response = $next($request);
          // Run you code here. 
          return $response
      }
}
```

Then modify your `App\Http\Kernel.php` middleware:

```
protected $middleware = [
       //Existing entries
       \App\Http\Middleware\PostProcess::class
];
```

That middleware will run after the response has been generated but before the response is sent to the client. If you want to run the code **after** the response was sent to the client you can use [terminable middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware#terminable-middleware)

```
class PostProcess {

      public function handle($request, $next) {
          return $next($request);
      }

      public function terminate($request, $response) {
         //Your code here 
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Step1 : Create Middleware

```
php artisan make:middleware PostProcess
```

Step2 : Make a code which you need

```
class PostProcess {

      public function handle($request, $next) {
          if(condition){
              you code here
          }
          return $next($request);
      }
}
```

Step3 : Call middleware in kernel.php

```
 protected $routeMiddleware = [
     'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\PostProcess::class,
 ];
```

Step 4: Call middleware in route file

```
 Route::group(['middleware' => 'admin'], function() {

 });
```